# Java: Developing an application (desktop) and make it only executable on Linux and not on other platforms

Tags: java, mono

but of strange question here, but i have an existing windows product developed with .net framework and i want to create an equivalent for java - i don't want to use mono

Java will actually execute on every platform that has a JVm, anyway to lock this down?

I don't want it to be runnable on windows for example.

With regards to mono, i have nothing against it but Java seems to have more compatible libraries. Anyone have any comments on this?

Comment: The lockdown part is a valid question. The poll about Mono vs Java is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`System.getProperty("os.name")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String))to detect the operating system in the main method, then exit the application if it's not what you expect.